# Read and replace text in HTML causes high CPU load

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, html5-video, innerhtml

I have a problem with high CPU load on a website where I want to replace some text with links.

The script is loaded at the end of body.

This works normally when there are no videos on the page. But if there are videos embedded like this the CPU load goes above 50%. If I use this for multiple files Firefox crashes.

```
<p><video width="320" height="240" class="mediaelement" autoplay="autoplay" src="video.mp4" controls="controls"><a href="video.mp4">resources/video.mp4</a></video></p>
```

I figured out the problem is in this, especially the readout from csv. If I just replace the text with fixed data it works as well.

```
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "data.csv", false);
    rawFile.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
      {
          var allText = rawFile.responseText;
          allText = allText.split("\n"); 
          var sizedata = Object.size(allText); //Number of  entries
          var sizedata =  sizedata -1; //Excel +1 
          //alert("Debug: " + sizedata);

          var i = 0;
          while (i < sizedata)
              {
                  var word = allText[i].split(";");
                  var wordToDefine = word[0];
                  var wordDefinition = word[1];
                  var wordToReplace = wordToDefine

                  var replaceItem = new RegExp(wordToReplace,"g");

                  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(replaceItem, " <a href='data.html' target='_self'><span style='color:green' title='WORD'>WORD</span></a>");  
                  i = i+1;
              }
      }
    }              
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
```

Any ideas what I can do about this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change the DOM requires a lot of CPU and you should limit it. Putting a .innerHTML inside a loop make the DOM of your website to refresh several times.
Consider to use a string and add your HTML at each iteration, then use innerHTML outside loop

Answer (score 1):

As  @criz already mentioned, building DOM in a loop is a very bad practice. It's much better to create documentFragment and attach it to the DOM.  Take a look at the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment There is an example.

Comment: Thank you all. I'm a bit lost here. I get that the changes should only be done once the page is loaded. But I thought I just did that. I'm just looping through the rows in my csv files.

Comment: Why is the script running even after page has loaded?