# Use Document.createDocumentFragment() instead of inner.html

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have this working code fragment:

```
var replaceItem = new RegExp(wordToReplace,"g");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(replaceItem, " <a href='test.html' target='_self'><span style='color:green' title='"+word+"'>"+word+"</span></a>");
```

How can I do this with Document.createDocumentFragment() to make it more efficient?

Comment: Please just google it. There are plenty of tutorials and resources on the web. E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Comment: I did already, but how can I search for text and replace it?

Comment: I see, you want to bind a variable to the DOM. I would suggest you to write a helper function that creates the part of the DOM, assuming you want to make regular updated to that DOM node.

Comment: It just has to update once to replace multiple text fragments with a link. The data comes from a CSV. However when having videos on that page the CPU load goes up.

Comment: So you want to initially replace when the page loads? Could you please add more information/context to your question.

Comment: Ok, the page contains some keywords. These have to be replaced with the above link including some variables. The data is read from a csv file row by row. The data is static so no more changes are required. However with innerHTML CPU is at 50%, so this is not a solution. Actually the question came up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189823/read-and-replace-text-in-html-causes-high-cpu-load